# Spliting a python list with two delimeters

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, python-requests

I started learning python. I am wondering how to split a list that has two delimiters.

INPUT

```
1,2,3,4,5;2
```

My code:

```
with open(path, 'r') as f:
for fs in f:
    ip= fs.rstrip('\n').split(',')
    print (ip)
```

My output:

```
['1', '2', '3', '4', '5;2']
```

Desired output

```
['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '2']
```

Can i please now how to remove the semicolon in the list.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can translate all the separators to a single one, say with
`replace` or `translate`:

with

> `str.replace(old, new[, max])`

You could do this:

> `print str.replace(";", ",")`

and then split

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_replace.htm

Answer (score 0):

Use regex to replace such `;` to `,`

```
import re
new_input=re.sub(';',',','1,2,3,4,5;2')
print(new_input.split(','))
```